# Сортировка и итераторы

Tags: указатели, структуры, итераторы, c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в функции `sortByMarksCoeff`, реализации ее действий. Еще не имел дело с итераторами и библиотекой <vector> и поэтому не пойму как осуществляется реализация этой функции.

```
  struct Student
    {
        char*    nameSurname;
        bool     budgetary;
        int      marks[5];
        int      scholarship;

        Student* next,
               * prev;
    };

    struct Group
    {
        int      groupNum;

        Student* head,
               * tail;

        Group*   next,
             *   prev;
    };

    struct University
    {
        int groupsAmount;

        Group* head, 
             * tail;
    };

double getMarksCoeff(Group* group)/средний балл контрактников к среднему баллу бюджетников
{
    if(!group)
        return 0;

    Student* ptr = group->head;
    double b_coeff = 0;
    double c_coeff = 0;

    int c_num = 0, b_num = 0;

    while(ptr)
    {
        double coeff = 0;

        for(int c = 0; c < 5; ++c)
            coeff += ptr->marks[c];

        if(ptr->budgetary)
        {
            ++b_num;
            b_coeff += coeff;
        }
        else
        {
            ++c_num;
            c_coeff += coeff;
        }
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    if(c_num && b_num)
    {
        c_coeff /= c_num;
        b_coeff /= b_num;

        if(b_coeff != 0)
            return c_coeff/b_coeff;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool sortByMarksCoeff(University* univer) /*сортировка групп в порядке убывания отношения среднего бала контрактников к среднему балу бюджетников*/
{
    struct MarkedGroup
    {
        Group* group;
        double mark;

        MarkedGroup(Group* in_group, double in_mark)
            : group(in_group), mark(in_mark) {}
    };

    vector<MarkedGroup> groups;

    if(!univer)
        return false;

    Group* ptr = univer->head;

    while(ptr)
    {
        groups.push_back(MarkedGroup(ptr, getMarksCoeff(ptr)));

        ptr = ptr -> next;
    }

    if(groups.empty())
        return 0;

    auto iter = groups.begin();
    auto end = groups.end();

    for(iter; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        auto iter2 = iter + 1;
        auto end2 = groups.end();

        for(iter2; iter2 != end2; ++iter2)
        {
            if(iter2->mark < iter->mark)
            {
                MarkedGroup buf = *iter2;
                *iter2 = *iter;
                *iter = buf;
            }
        }
    }

    univer->head = univer->tail = NULL;

    iter = groups.begin();
    end = groups.end();

    for(iter; iter != end; ++iter)
        addGroup(univer, iter->group, true);

    return true;
}f
```

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, что конкретно вам непонятно?

Answer (score 1):

Прежде всего стоит обратить внимание вообще на подход к решению задачи, а именно явным ее усложнением. Этот код на Си, а не C++, так что сперва его надо переписать:

1. Сплошь и рядом оперируете с "голыми" указателями, что рано или поздно станет причиной больших проблем (в вашем случае - точно!). Вместо них стоит использовать [smart_ptr](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/cpp/smartptr.xml)`ы.
2. Строки, например `Student::nameSurname`, реализованы через голые указатели - `char*`, и при этом нет ни конструктора, ни деструктора класса `Student`, соответственно кто контролирует память - не понятно. В C++ для строк есть класс `std::string`, который для этого куда пригоднее.
3. Не нужно самостоятельно строить списки на указателях - для этого есть стандартный контейнер `std::list`. Использование стандартных контейнеров существенно упростит код, а также позволит применять для сортировки и обработки всех элементов готовые алгоритмы.

Очень краткое описание стандартной библиотеки C++: [Стандартная библиотека языка C++](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0_C%2B%2B).

Чувство, что вы не знакомы с возможностями языка C++, а **пытаетесь разобраться в нем методом научного тыка - не тратьте время впустую - ибо из этого ничего не выйдет**. Начините с азов - прочтите хотя бы одну две-хорошие книги.

Comment: smart_ptr не безопасен, лучше использовать shared_ptr или unique_ptr из нового стандарта.

Comment: @IronVbif, тем не менее, и у auto_ptr есть вполне подходящий режим использования, хотя бы как замена Си-указателю на динамически выделенный агрегат класса, которым никто другой не владеет.

Comment: Позвольте не согласиться с утверждением, что raw-указатели рано или поздно приведут к ошибкам. Никогда не имел проблем ни с пониманием, ни с использованием таких указателей. На мой взгляд *_ptr'ы - сложность, ложно принимаемая за глубину

Comment: @renegator, значит, вы их правильно использовали - поздравляю! Но злоупотребление ими, а тем более в неопытных руках, может привести к большим сложностям при росте программы: это сильно затрудняет как отладку, так рост и сопровождение. В моногомодульной системе, где связность минимальная, ими пользоваться не стоит.

Comment: имея двадцатилетний опыт написания очень многомодульных систем все же предложу Вам быть не столь категоричным

Answer (score 0):

Функция по-видимому предназначена для загрузки процессора бесполезными операциями копирования и пузырьковой сортировкой. Более бестолкового кода я не видел.